# How to save text input as a file in HTML and Django

Tags: html, django, file, text, django-models

I am building a site where users can input text and submit the text so that it can be saved and accessed as a file on the server. Unfortunately, I am not quite sure how I would take the inputted text and save it aas a file.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how I might do this or detail the steps I will have to take? Preemptive apologizes if I have missed an obvious Google result. Being somewhat new to Django, I may have inadvertently glossed over helpful resources.

Here is the relevant HTML, mostly a form copied from a file upload form:

```
<form name="myWebForm" id="submissionCode_codeEditor" action="uploadFile/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="500" />
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="File Name"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="taskID" value={{ taskID }} />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit This Code" />
</form>
```

Here is the relevant Django model:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    fileUpload = models.FileField(upload_to='file_uploads')
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    uploadTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Are you familiar with django forms or modelforms ?

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar. I set them up for the fileUpload system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class). It's a Django `File` subclass that instantiates with a string of text instead of a literal file. You can then save the `ContentFile` to your `FileField`.

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

content = ContentFile(some_text)
upload_instance.fileUpload.save('/path/to/where/file/should/save.txt', content)
upload_instance.save()
```

Comment: I'm a bit stuck. How does one link the inputed string to the ContentFile? I imagine there is some link between the "some_text" argument in your example and some html attribute that should be in my textarea. Or am I wrong in needing to reference these things because Django provides that functionality for free?

Comment: If the information is coming from a form, then `some_text` would just be something like `request.POST['my_text_field_name']`. You should sanitize anything user-submitted before actually saving it to your filesystem, though.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I'll make sure to address that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a file in your media folder using command, i am assuming user posted text with name content

```
from app.models import Upload
from django.conf import settings
content = request.GET("content")
file_object = open("%s/%s"%(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, filename),w)  #Take file name as hash of content posted and username so that no class
upload = Upload(title=title, fileUpload=filename,user_id=request.user.id)
```

Your file is uploaded and can be acceseed using MEDIA_URL from settings

Comment: Is this something I would add in addition to Chris Pratt's answer? Or is this an alternative method?

Comment: no chris method is different for just uploading the file. I considered  updating your model enteries.